# How to unregister an event handler in Internet Explorer 6?

Tags: javascript, events, httphandler

I am registering a function with the onload method of a html form, I need to unregister this event hander function on unload of the form. How do I do it in Internet Explorer 6?

Comment: Thanks, I could get it working based on Dimi's reference.

Thanks for your comments too meouw.

Answer (score 7):

if you have added the onload in your HTML or via JavaScript

```
<form onload="blah()">
```

or

```
myForm.onload = blah;
```

then

```
myForm.onload = null;
```

should do it
if you've used attachEvent

```
myForm.attachEvent( 'onload', blah );
```

use

```
myForm.detachEvent( 'onload', blah );
```

**EDIT**
I'm not sure forms have onload events tho, are you sure?

Answer (score 3):

Use detachEvent

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536411(VS.85).aspx)